# How to get only active element from many to many relationship with translation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with a many to many relationship and the translations of the terms.
I have 4 tables:

```
products
    - id, price, whatever
products_lang
    - id, product_id, lang, product_name
accessori
    - id, active
accessori_lang
    - id, accessori_id, lang, accessori_name
```

I'm trying to assign accessories to products with an intermediate table named:

```
accessori_products
```

this is the model for Product:

```
class Product extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function productsLang () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductLng', 'products_id')->where('lang','=',App::getLocale());
    }

    public function productsLangAll() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductLng', 'products_id');
    }

    public function accessori() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Accessori', 'accessori_products');
    }
}
```

this is the model for productLng:

```
class ProductLng extends Model {

    protected $table = 'products_lng';

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'products_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then I have the model for Accessori:

```
class Accessori extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accessori';

    public function accessoriLang() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AccessoriLng')->where('lang','=',App::getLocale());
    }

    public function accessoriLangAll() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AccessoriLng');
    }

    public function accessoriProducts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'accessori_products', 'accessori_id', 'products_id');
    }
}
```

And the model for AccessoriLng:

```
class accessoriLng extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accessori_lng';

    public function accessori() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Accessori', 'accessori_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I get the results by this:

```
$products = Product::has('accessori')->with([
  'productsLang ',
  'accessori' => function ($accessori){
      $accessori->with([
        'accessoriLang'
      ]);
   }
])->get();

return $products;
```

but I want to get only the active accessories something like `where accessori.active = 1` but I really don't know where to put it. I've tried in different way but I'm stuck on it by 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC you don't need a model for the intermediate table on your many to many relationships.

If you want to return Products where Accessori is active you can use `whereHas` on the Product model.

```
$prod = Product::whereHas('accessori', function($query) {
  $query->where('active', 1);
})->get();
```

Where the `$query` param will be running on the Accessori model.

You can do the inverse as well with Accessori to Product.

```
$acessoris = Accessori::where('active', 1)->whereHas('accessoriProduct')->with(['accessoriLang', 'accessoriProducts.productsLang'])->get();
```

Comment: I need the list of active accessories then I need to find those related to the product and their translation

Comment: this is almost correct, but it's not what I was trying to do, anyway I upvoted your answer because it helped me to understand where the error was

Comment: I guess I am unsure what you want to do. What was the error?